ESP32 FreeRTOS crashes when calling callback between tasks
I'm trying to implement the observer pattern on ESP32H2 device (devkit) ESP-IDF v5.2.1. I have 2 FreeRTOS tasks (in 2 files), there is a register callback function in one file, which is used to pass a callback to be called, when the second task is ready to pass data to the first one.
// task1.c
typedef void (*func)(int, struct myStruct);

void myCallback(int e, struct myStruct ms) { // <-- here is the problem
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "myCallback is called %d, %f", e, ms.value);
}

void task1(void *args) {
  while (1) {
    ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, pdMS_TO_TICKS(5000));
    request(myCallback);
  }
}

// task2.c
static func callback;

static void notifyObservers(int e, struct myStruct ms) {
  callback(e, ms);
}

void request(func cb) {
  callback = cb;
  xTaskNotifyGive(task2Handle);
}

void task2(void *args) {
  struct myStruct result;

  while (1) {
    ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, portMAX_DELAY);
    // some logic goes here...
    notifyObservers(0, result);
  }
}

// main.c
void app_main(void) {
  // create tasks task1Handle = xTaskCreateStatic(task1,...); task2Handle = ...;
}

When the callback has a signature void f(int e); or void f(int e, struct myStruct *ms); everything works as expected: task1 wakes up once in 5 s, requests action from task2. Task2 unblocks, performs some logic (with delays), then calls the passed callback, callback logs the specified text.
But when the signature is changed to void f(int e, struct myStruct ms); calling the callback crashes the app with Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Stack protection fault). ESP32 error documentation. Also there is Load access fault which describes MTVAL register value (in my case it's 0x00008082). So I can suggest that the problem with the struct instance and the stack.
I always thought that a struct is copied by value when passed as the argument to a function, so there should not be the big difference from int e case which is also passed by value. Also as far as I know the callback is running in context of task2 (even defined in task1 scope), and every task in FreeRTOS is allocated its own stack memory block.
So why does void f(int e); work and void f(int e, struct myStruct ms); doesn't?
UPD1:
struct myStruct {
  float value;
  uint8_t size;
  struct {
    float data;
    uint64_t id;
  } data[8];
};

I use #define STACK_SIZE 2048 for tasks stack. But also increased its value by 2. It crashes all the same. If I'm correct a struct instance is 808 bytes long.

If your struct is large there may not be enough space (on the stack) to copy it there. That is why, usually, people pass pointers to structs rather than the structs proper.

If I were asking a question about why my code crashes when I pass a struct as an argument, I would include the definition of the struct.

@romkey, Thanks for advice, updated the post to define the struct.

808 * 3 > 2048 ... why 3? you ask ... well 1 in task2() copied to call notifyObserver() and another copy there to call callback()

Actually I retested the code. And found that to make it work I need to increase stack in both tasks. Before that I've increased stack size for FreeRTOS task only for task2. And the app crashed. If I increase stack size only for task1, it also crashes. Only when increasing for both, it works as expected. Don't understand why actually? @pmg Thank you, I missed the point that we are creating stack frame for each function call and each has its copy of the struct instance. One part is demistified. :) So why do we need to increase task1 stack size?
